# 2-in-1 with matte screen

Tags: laptop

I am on market for a new laptop, but all of my online search, as well as communications with sales people didn't yield any 2-in-1 with matte screen, which is surprising. I know it is possible to make matte touchscreens - so I am hoping someone has made a matte 2-in-1.

additional desired specs include:

- portable: light-weight, 13" to 14" in screen size.
- durable (I am willing to invest, if there is a good chance the laptop will last for 10 years).
- an OS that can be over-written. This may be a stupid spec, but I have heard that macOS and Chromebook OS are hard to get rid of. I intend to install Linux, and I want to make sure that would be possible.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the solution was Lenovo Thinkpad X1 series, in case anyone else is wondering.

Comment: Which exact laptop am I wondering?